# Автоматический поворот картинки

Tags: php, jquery

Привет всем. 
Столкнулся с такой необычной ситуацией. 
У меня на сайте есть функция загрузки фотографии. Сегодня заметил что фотки из программы ретрика не правильно отображаются именно при и после загрузки. 
Для наглядного примера зайдите на сайт: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-avatar-upload-demo

И вставьте эту фотку в поле.
http://celebizade.info/retrica.jpg

На компе нормально отображается, а когда вставляем автоматически переворачивается. Причём именно фотки из ретрика) Как такое вообще возможно?
Кстати при загрузке на сервер через пхп тоже самое, в перевораченном виде)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот дамп информации об изображении, который находится внутри вашего JPG:

```
{
          'width' => 2592,
          'DateTime' => '2016:09:12 14:43:08',
          'file_media_type' => 'image/jpeg',
          'Tag-0x9208' => 0,
          'file_ext' => 'jpg',
          'Tag-0x9003' => '2016:09:12 14:43:08',
          'color_type' => 'YCbCr',
          'Model' => 'Lenovo P1a42',
          'Tag-0x9286' => 'i. 100%',
          .....
          'BitsPerSample' => [ 8, 8, 8 ],
          'SamplesPerPixel' => 3,
          'Tag-0x9207' => 65535,
          'height' => 1944,
          'Orientation' => 'right_top',
          'Software' => 'Retrica',
          'Make' => 'Lenovo',
          'resolution' => '1/1',
          'JPEG_Type' => 'Baseline'
        };
```

Как видите в каждом изображении содержится много дополнительной информации. Особенно обратите внимание на поле `'Orientation' => 'right_top'`. Это поле означает, что при съемке аппарат был повернут на 90 градусов. Программы просмотра изображений обычно учитывают этот факт и поворачивают фото на экране так, что бы компенсировать поворот аппарата в момент съемки. А вот программы, создающие более мелкие изображения для аватарок часто не учитывают этого, и после конвертации теги ориентации так же не переносят. Правильная программа преобразования изображений должна посмотреть на теги ориентации и повернуть картинку перед тем как делать ее уменьшенную копию.